# Stop angular $timeout timer after hitting back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, settimeout, back

In my Angular app, I have Page 1, and Page 2.

**Page 1** is basically the home page with a button linking to Page 2.

Page 1 has an angular app called **Page1App** and a controller called **Page1Ctrl**.
Page 2 has an angular app called **Page2App** and a controller called **Page2Ctrl**.

**Page1App** has **Page2App** as a dependency.

```
angular.module('Page1App', ['Page2App']);
```

In Page 2, there is a timer, that works like the timer in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/vqVrX/) (code duplicated below)

```
 $scope.nextPic = function() {
      $timeout.cancel(picTimeout)
      if (++$scope.picIndex >= $scope.pics.length) $scope.picIndex=0
      picTimeout = $timeout($scope.nextPic, 2000)
  }

  $scope.prevPic = function() {
      $timeout.cancel(picTimeout)
      if (--$scope.picIndex < 0 ) $scope.picIndex=$scope.pics.length-1
      picTimeout = $timeout($scope.nextPic, 2000)
  }
  picTimeout = $timeout($scope.nextPic, 2000)
```

The problem is, when I go back to **Page 1** from **Page 2**, the timer continues running in the background, and occasionally makes an `alert` pop up - which is OK if you are on Page 2, but not OK if you already left Page 2.

How do I make everything from Page 2 stop when the user leaves it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for scope destroy event listener and clear the timeout.

for Ex:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $timeout.cancel(picTimeout);
});
```

check the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for `$destroy` event of scopes.

Comment: cool I'd never heard of `$destroy`... and I forgot about `$scope.$on`  I'll try it out. Thanks a lot

Comment: oky give it a try  and update if it is working or not.. :) cheerz

Comment: where do I place this code? Anywhere in the controller?

Comment: yes put it inside the `controller` which u defined the `$timeout`. you can put at the end of the `controller` so it will looks cleaner. :)